# Python/MySQL query syntax causes TypeError

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

On running this code segment, I get `TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting',)`.

```
write_query = "insert into %s_semantic (anchor,old_url,semantic_url) values (?,?,?)" %category
try:
    cursor.execute(write_query,(result[0],result[1],str(contextual_redirect)))
except Exception as e:
    print "DB write failed for %s beacuse %s" %(result[0],str(repr(e)))
```

What is wrong with the above query syntax?

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb uses `%s` as placeholder, not `?`.

Since you are also doing string substitution on that SQL to insert the table name, you will need to double the `%` signs in the original string.

Comment: `"insert into %%s_semantic (anchor,old_url,semantic_url) values (?,?,?)" %category` something like this?